# jQuery, discover what a dom object's class are

Tags: javascript, jquery, class

I have a .click() on several buttons. Each .click() calls a function. The function needs to know which button called it so that it can show or hide different content and change the styles of the other buttons. The function has an event object passed to it.

Is there a way I can get the current class that the event object has?

Answer (score 2):

```
$('myButton').click(function() {
    var className = this.className; // This will give you the whole class string of the clicked element
    var hasClass = $(this).hasClass('myClass'); // This will tell you (true or false) whether the clicked element has class 'myClass'
});
```

Comment: This is good, because I won't know the class name before hand.

Comment: In this case is this the same as the event object that click passes to the function?

Comment: It's not the event object, it's the DOM element that triggered the click. (Which would be the same as the `target` or `srcElement` of the event object).

Answer (score 1):

You can get the class with [`.className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/DOM/element.classname) or [`.attr("class")`](http://api.jquery.com/attr/), though what you probably *want* is to have `this` refer to the button, for example:

```
$(".selector").click(myFunction);

function myFunction() {
  //this == button that was clicked
  var c = this.className;
}
```

Or an inline function:

```
$(".selector").click(function () {
  var c = this.className;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you are passing this to a function (though depending how you are doing this, some code would be nice!), if you pass e as the first parameter in the function then you can use e.target.className to get the class, or, with jQuery $(e.target).attr('class');

Answer (score -1):

Couldn't you make different functions for the different `.click()` calls?

Comment: I'm going to end up with between 25 and 35 .click() calls. I'd rather they all call one function rather than have 25 or 35 different functions.